# Low Seg2Cat not working with category groups

Tags: low-seg2cat

Am using Low Seg2Cat. Great utility. But having problems now using it with categories in a second category group.

For categories in the initial category group it works fine.
For categories in the second category group I created it generates no responses.

The behavior can be tested on a url generated by this code:

```
Segment 3 - {segment_3}<br />
Segment 3 Group ID - {segment_3_category_group_id}<br />
Segment 3 Category Name - {segment_3_category_name}<br />
Segment 3 Description - {segment_3_category_description}<br />

<h2>category source information</h2> 

{exp:channel:categories}
    <a href="/pages/_categorytest/{category_url_title}">{category_name}</a> (Category ID/url: {category_id}/{category_url_title})
    {if category_description}{category_description}{/if}
{/exp:channel:categories}
```

In my dataset, categories 1-10 are in Group 1, Categories 11 and up are in Group 2.

Here is a URL generated by the above code for a category in the first group:
http://2gc.eu/pages/_categorytest/presentations

Here is a URL generated by the above code for a category in the second group:
http://2gc.eu/pages/_categorytest/balanced-scorecard

You will see that the Low Seg2Cat tags generate no data for the second example, even though there is data available.

Any idea why this is happening?  I'm sure I'm doing something silly - but documentation for Low Seg2Cat implies that if you don't specify Group-ID in the tag parameters, the results are for all categories.

Grateful for whatever guidance you can offer on this.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Speedy response from Low - in case useful to anyone else - I had forgotten to add second group to the Low Seg2Cat CP settings.

Did this and all worked sensibly again :)

Thanks Low!